# How can I improve the predictive power of a CNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using a CNN in TensorFlow with two convolution layers, a single fully-connected layer and a linear layer to predict object sizes. The labels are sizes and the features are images.

To assess the performance of the network, I am using five-fold cross validation. Using TensorBoard I plot the accuracy for both the training set and the cross-validation set.

Both accuracies increase, but the cross-validation accuracy increases more slowly. Thinking the divergence in accuracies is due to the model overfitting, I tried to regularize the weights using L2 regularization. But, this just reduced the training accuracy, while the trend in cross-validation accuracy remained the same. The cross-validation accuracy always remains below 50%.

Can anyone recommend a few methods I might consider to improve the cross-validation accuracy and hence the predictive power of the model? Thank you very much.

[without regularization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdCas.png) Training accuracy is in gray, cross-validation accuracy is in green.

[with regularization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvRLu.png) Training accuracy is in blue, cross-validation accuracy is in red.

Comment: I've found that adding dropout layers can significantly improve accuracy. I'd also experiment with batch sizes. With image classification, I've had good results with small batch sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting has multiple remedies. To name a few:

- **Regularization**: instead of L2 regularization, you can try adding Dropout layers and see how the model fares. Dropout layers deactivate certain neurons during training, forcing the model to rely on the other ones as well.
- **Data augmentation**: there are multiple techniques to augment your training data. You can either generate new images with image processing techniques or make your existing images more "CNN-friendly". Some keywords to search for are data centering and normalization/standardization, zca whitening, traditional image processing such as zoom/crop, invert, color filters, shift/skew, distort and rotate functions as well as [NN-based data augmentation techniques](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/300.pdf).
- **Model architecture**: changing your model architecture will result higher (overfitting) or lower (underfitting) loss of generality. Experiment with the number of layers, size of convolutional kernel and consider using pre-trained networks (transfer learning) such as Inception v3, AlexNet, GoogLeNet, VGG-16, etc.

There are certainly a million other ways but this is a great place to start.